# Changing the path of jQuery to use a CDN instead of the local file system

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript, cdn

I am creating a custom theme and I would like to know how to update the path of jQuery to use a CDN like the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I don't want to use another module. I just want a simple way to change the path of the script.

Comment: There's an [example using `hook_js_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7#comment-32683) on the docs page that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the template.php file of your theme. (Replace mytheme with the actual short name of your theme.)

```
function mytheme_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['type'] = 'external';
  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
}
```

As you are replacing the copy of the jQuery library with the same version copy hosted on Google, it doesn't make much sense to do it for just a theme. It would make sense to change it independently from the theme used from Drupal.

If you plan to use a different version of the library, you should first check there aren't incompatibilities with the jQuery version, and JavaScript code used from Drupal, or third-party modules. In case of incompatibilities, some JavaScript files used by Drupal could need to be replaced (using `hook_js_alter()`). That is what the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module does.